# UART - Reduce 4 V to 3 V

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, uart, digital-communications

I have a 4 V microcontroller communicating with a SoC over UART (most likely 9600 baud), whereby the maximum input voltage on the SoC's RX input is 3.1 V. Because of this, I'd like to step the logic level down from 4 V to 3 V.

I'd like to use a simple potential divider to achieve this, however, I've seen diodes used for this purpose, and I am wondering if there's an advantage to this (or another) method that I'm missing.

Additionally, I'm not sure which resistor values to choose; would I size the resistors at at few ohms, a few hundred, a few thousand?

Comment: Is it one way communication from 4V to 3V or is it (semi) duplex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, the reason diodes are used is to avoid increasing the impedance of the signal source. This would help if for some reason the next stage has an unknown, unpredictable or perhaps reactive input impedance. For instance, long cables will introduce both capacitive and inductive elements into the load.

To see this, we can model the two approaches, diodes vs. resistor divider, under such conditions (which I exaggerated here, for illustration):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftsnsQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The boxed regions represent some ill-behaved load, that your UART might have to drive, which may be long meandering cables, or a low impedance input, or any number of unpredictable conditions. The signals actually received will be OUT1 and OUT2, looking like this:

[image]

As you can see, even though I chose resistances to attenuate to about 80%, the resistor divider solution has suffered much greater attenuation, more like 60%, and significant distortion. The signal derived from the diodes, however, survived much more intact.

Even though the diodes drop 0.6V each, their effective impedance when they are forward biased remains very low, near zero. That means the load may draw as much current as it needs without causing the voltage across the diodes to increase any further.

Also, the diode's low impedance means that the \$RC\$ or \$\frac{L}{R}\$ time constants associated with any parasitic capacitance or inductance will be correspondingly low, and signal rise and fall times remain short.

By comparison, the signal from the resistor divider has a high source impedance. That impedance "drops" a voltage which is always proportional to the current drawn from it, so a current hungry load will receive a heavily attenuated signal.

That high impedance also combines with parasitic reactances with much longer \$RC\$ and \$\frac{L}{R}\$ time constants, forming a filter with low cut-off frequency, and severely slowing signal rise and fall.

#### Calculating Divider Resistances

When choosing resistances for a potential divider, you must consider the maximum current that your UART can source/sink, and the current that will be drawn at the destination. Your resistors must be able to supply current to any expected load without excessive attenuation, and the combined current draw of you divider and target load cannot exceed the UART's rated maximum output current.

There are many ways you could go about this, but here's a reasonable approach.

Start by finding out what current your destination's input will draw, when presented with the voltage you want there, 3V. Let's say that's 100μA, worst case.

As an approximation, it's fair to say that whatever the current is, passing down the *unloaded* resistor divider chain, if I started drawing some small fraction X of that current from the junction, then the potential there would change by a factor of about X too, because of Ohm's law. That's not exactly true, but it's close enough as long as X is small.

Therefore, if I want the signal arriving at the destination to be within 10% of the ideal 3V, then my resistor divider must pass *at least* 10 times the current that will be diverted from it, into that target input:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{MIN} &= \frac{100\mu A}{10\%} \\ \\
&= 1mA
\end{aligned}
$$

We require attenuation from 4V to 3V, which will determine the ratio of the resistances:

$$
\begin{aligned}
4\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} &= 3 \\ \\
4R_2 &= 3R_1 + 3R_2 \\ \\
R_2 &= 3R_1 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The current through the resistances will depend on the UART's output voltage (4V), and also the sum of R1 and R2 (since they are in series, between the UART's output and ground). We know that this should be *at least* 1mA, allowing us to calculate a maximum value for their sum, using Ohm's law:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_1 + R_2 &= \frac{V_{UART}}{I_{MIN}} \\ \\
&= \frac{4V}{1mA} \\ \\
&= 4k\Omega
\end{aligned}
$$

So, whatever values we choose for R1 and R2, their sum cannot exceed 4kΩ. We know their ratio, so we can find maxima for them individually:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_2 &= 3R_1 \\ \\
R_1 + R_2 &= 4k\Omega \\ \\
R_1 + 3R_1 &= 4k\Omega \\ \\
4R_1 &= 4k\Omega \\ \\
R_1 &= 1k\Omega \\ \\
R_2 &= 3k\Omega
\end{aligned}
$$

Now we consider the UART, its capabilities and safety. Find out the absolute minimum combined resistance R1+R2 that we can permit. Let's say that the datasheet tells us the maximum current that the UART can output is 20mA. By Ohm's law:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_{MIN} &= \frac{V_{UART}}{I_{MAX}} \\ \\
R_{MIN} &= \frac{4V}{20mA} \\ \\
&= 200\Omega \\ \\
R_1 + R_2 &\ge 200\Omega
\end{aligned}
$$

Individual minima are then:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_2 &= 3R_1 \\ \\
R_1 + R_2 &= 200\Omega \\ \\
R_1 + 3R_1 &= 200\Omega \\ \\
4R_1 &= 200\Omega \\ \\
R_1 &= 50\Omega \\ \\
R_2 &= 150\Omega
\end{aligned}
$$

We have some room to manoeuvre:

$$
50\Omega \le R_1 \le 1k\Omega \\ \\
200\Omega \le R_2 \le 3k\Omega \\ \\
$$

It might be helpful to try and protect the UART from accidental short circuit of its output to ground. We already calculated the smallest resistance permissible between the UART's output and ground, \$R_{MIN}=200\Omega\$. If we set \$R_1=R_{MIN}\$, we can model such a short circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flhRgh.png)</sup>

Since a value of \$R_{MIN}\$ lies within our calculated range of acceptable values for R1, we could settle on values here and now:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_1 &= 200\Omega \\ \\
R_2 &= 600\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Any values within the acceptable ranges we calculated would do, but generally go with lower value resistances to minimise attenuation and interference, and higher values for power efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a series resistor. 22k to 100k will be just fine. Nothing more is necessary. You don't need a divider.